# What is difference between connect vs Bound? In terms of BLE

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I want to communicate with sensorTag. For that i connect to BLE using mac id .For communication i  write/read on/from BluetoothGattCharacteristic .Its working all fine.Now my question is, if I am able to do it without pairing then in which scenario we use pairing/Bounding .

Answer (score 1):

With pairing the devices exchange security information (aka keys) only temporary for the current connection. When they disconnect and then reconnet, they need pairing a second time and so on.
With bonding, the devices save permanently security information so that for each disconnection, they don't need to execute this exchange thanks to the saved information (exchanged before during bonding).

Paolo.

Comment: so first time device need to be paired using pin.Now next if both the device comes into range will it reconnect automatically?

Comment: Yes. BLE supports pairing without pin too. However it depends on the BLE device.